# C++ Closing Socket to initiate new connection

Tags: c++, sockets

I am new to socket programming in C++. 
I've made a simple port scanner that scan one port and it worked as expected.

Now I'm trying to scan multiple ports So I create a socket and started iterating over an array of ports, BUT all ports appears as closed.

My Question is: *Do i have to close socket in order to scan another port ?*

Code is bellow:

```
    // This Code scan correctly
    // ------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 260000; //750000 = 0.75s

        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            std::cout << "Cannot set RCV timeout\n";
        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            std::cout << "Cannot set SND timeout\n";

        struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
        srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        srv_addr.sin_port = htons(ports[i]);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.100.1", &srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

        int connection_result = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr));
        if(connection_result == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Port Open\n";
            close(sock_fd);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Port closed\n";
            close(sock_fd);
        }
    }
```

But this code **where i create/close socket outside the for loop**  shows all ports as closed!

```
        // Shows all ports close
        // ----------------------
        int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
        //int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 100000; //750000 = 0.75s
        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            std::cout << "Cannot set RCV timeout\n";
        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            std::cout << "Cannot set SND timeout\n";
        struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
        srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        srv_addr.sin_port = htons(ports[i]);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.100.1", &srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
        int connection_result = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr));
        if(connection_result == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Port Open\n";
            //close(sock_fd);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Port closed\n";
            //close(sock_fd);
        }

        }
        close(sock_fd);
```

Comment: Please don't use the term "C/C++" or tag both languages. They are two distinct and very different languages, and you're most likely programming in only one of them, not both.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok i updated the question

Comment: As for your problem, the answer is: Yes, you must close the socket between connections.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently i must close the socket between each connection, **Thanks to Some programmer dude**

So I changed my code now I create/close socket inside the for loop.

Example below:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
        // Creating the socket
        // -------------------
        int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 260000; //260000 = 0.26s
        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            std::cout << "Cannot set RCV timeout\n";
        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            std::cout << "Cannot set SND timeout\n";
        struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
        srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        srv_addr.sin_port = htons(ports[i]);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.100.1", &srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
        int connection_result = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr));
        if(connection_result == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Port Open\n";
            // Closing the socket
            close(sock_fd);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Port closed\n";
            // Closing the socket
            close(sock_fd);
        }

        }
```

Comment: On SO, it's perfectly fine to provide an answer to your own question. But, as is, this is more of a comment than an answer. To make this a full answer, you should explain what you had to change. You could post the changed code in a code block here.